# Sign in with new Google account using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to sign in to my Google account from the below page:

[image]

The following Python program successfully opens Chrome with login but gives an error. Why the error occurred?

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/Users/s***/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

driver_path = "./chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)　# line 15`
```

error message

```
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\soras\OneDrive\デスクトップ\selenium-python\google-keep.py", line 15, in <module>
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\soras\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00756463+2188387]
        Ordinal0 [0x006EE461+1762401]
        Ordinal0 [0x00603D78+802168]
        Ordinal0 [0x00621F40+925504]
        Ordinal0 [0x0061E331+910129]
        Ordinal0 [0x00651430+1119280]
        Ordinal0 [0x0065108A+1118346]
        Ordinal0 [0x0064C5F6+1099254]
        Ordinal0 [0x00626BE0+945120]
        Ordinal0 [0x00627AD6+948950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009F71F2+2712546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009E886D+2652765]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007E002A+520730]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x007DEE06+516086]
        Ordinal0 [0x006F468B+1787531]
        Ordinal0 [0x006F8E88+1805960]
        Ordinal0 [0x006F8F75+1806197]
        Ordinal0 [0x00701DF1+1842673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75187BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7731BD2B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x7731BCAF+191]
```

[image]

wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: The error message should be more than this, please provide more as much as possible.

Comment: I edited my error message.
thank you for your advice.

Comment: Make sure the webdriver version you are using is compatible with your Chrome browser version,. If you use Linux, please try to give webdriver and other related path permissions and suggest to add `options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')`

Comment: You were right. because Chrome automatically updated, webdriver version is not compatible with chrome version. Thank you!